# override login with other user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, authentication

i am working with a asp.net mvc4 application.

and I have some logins. I have a salesagent(ShopAccountType) login with a username and password.

But now I have some other logins with only a code. So the intention is that a superaccount(SalesAgent) logs in with a username and password. And that then other sales agents(balie users) login with a code. So that the superaccount has to be overriden with a balie user code.

I have a controller class, like this:

```
 public class V_ExtendedProfileController : ProfileController
    {

        protected override void RegisterSystemRoutes(SanaRouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapSystemPageRoute("Profile", "BalieNr", "BalieNr", "Profile/BalieNr");

            base.RegisterSystemRoutes(routes);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult BalieNr()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [SanaValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult BalieNr(IEntityListLoadOptions options, ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel model, string accountSalesAgentID, Guid? accountID  /*string accountId, ShopAccountType accountType,Customer.ICustomerListLoadOptions hallo*/)
        {

            var salesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccounts(options);

            Entity SalesAgenWithBaliecodeNr = new Entity();
            //IShopAccount LoginSalesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccount(accountID, true);



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in salesAgent)
                {
                    if (item.ShopAccountType == ShopAccountType.SalesAgent)
                    {
                        if (model.Baliecode == "DB"    /*item.ReferenceId.Contains("HD")*/)
                        {
                            model.Name = "Dick Beekman";
                            var modelagent = ObjectManager.GetInstance<ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel>();
                            modelagent.Name = Shop.ShopAccount.Name;
                            modelagent.Name = model.Name;





                        }

                        //var customer = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson(accountID);
                        Console.WriteLine(accountID);

                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("false");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(salesAgent);



            return View();
        }




    }
```

And is all about the actionmethod: BalieNr.

And I have a view like this:

```
@{

    Layout = LayoutPaths.General;
}

@model Sana.Commerce.Customization.Account.ExtendedSalesAgentInfoModel

<div class="semicolumn">
    @*<div class="text">@Sana.RichText("Login_IntroductionText", makeImagesResponsive: true)</div>*@
    <div class="form-holder">
      @using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form" }))
      {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Baliecode)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Baliecode)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">


                @*@Sana.SubmitButton("Login", "btn btn-medium btn-login")*@
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So if I login with a superaccount. I see Welcome Hans Albert

but then I login as balie user with a code. In this case: DB.

and if I look and this:

```
 modelagent.Name = model.Name;
```

I see Dick Beekman on modelagent and model. But I still see:

Welcome Hans Albert.

So how to override the superaccount with the balie user?

Thank you

So how to overrirde an existing login with not a username and passward. But with just a baliecode(string). That is the question.

Thank you

Comment: Please revise your question to be more clear. This makes no sense.

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: has somebody any suggestion? Thank you